# What's involved in restoring a Linux system that's completely hosed?

Tags: backup

I am very nearly sold on switching from macOS to Linux as my main operating system. But there's a very important thing I can do with macOS that I can't find how to do with Linux: one-click recoverable, full system backups.

With macOS, I just set up Time Machine, and I don't have to worry about anything. No matter what I change on my system, its *all* backed up. And when my system becomes totally unusable, all I have to do is have a recovery OS--could be a partition on my HDD, could be a USB stick--format my drive and put everything back. In less than 90 minutes, I'm back in business.

Linux doesn't seem to have any equivalent. The best I can find is Déjà Dup, the [documentation for which](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/DejaDup/Help) has not been updated since 2013, and doesn't even describe how to set it up. There's also Cronopete, but it has no user documentation *at all*.

So what do Linux users do to solve this problem?

Comment: If Time Machine is your must-have application, the dealbreaker...then don't switch. We're not trying to sell you anything, and we gain nothing if you do switch to Ubuntu. We're volunteers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the `timeshift` package:

> Description: System restore utility
>
> Timeshift is a system restore
> utility which takes snapshots  of the system at regular intervals.
> These snapshots can be restored  at a later date to undo system
> changes. Creates incremental snapshots  using rsync or BTRFS snapshots
> using BTRFS tools.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you!